# How can i convert color?

Tags: php, base64

This Code result [enter image description here](http://i.hizliresim.com/Q27N0k.png) I would like to convert this resample pixel color to reverse ,Black pixel will be white, white pixel black
My it will be a question. How to convert white pixels to png format? [This İmage](http://i.hizliresim.com/Q27N0k.png)

```
  $width=10;
        $height=16;
        $resimBase64 = "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";

        $byteArray=array();
        foreach(str_split(base64_decode($resimBase64)) as $byte)
        {
            $byteArray[] = ord($byte);
        }
        //print_r($byteArray);
        //exit;
        header ('Content-type: image/png');
        $im = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height) or die('GD2 resim akımı ilklendirilemedi');
        //$black = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
        $i=0;

        for( $y=0;$y<$height;$y++){
            for( $x=0;$x<$width;$x++){
                //imagesetpixel($im,$x,$y,$black);
                $b=$byteArray[$i+0];
                $g=$byteArray[$i+1];
                $r=$byteArray[$i+2];
                $a=$byteArray[$i+3];
                $color=imagecolorallocate($im,$a,$a,$a);
                $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
                imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);
                //echo $a."<br/>\n";
                imagesetpixel($im,$x,$y,$color);
                $i=$i+4;
            }
        }
            imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe1Cn.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the GD library you can use an [imagefilter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) with the type `IMG_FILTER_NEGATE` (makes a negative).

This should do it:

```
header ('Content-type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($resimBase64));
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you ☺

Comment: ... once I remembered to `base64_decode()` the string first ;) @heatgreat

Answer (score 0):

My it will be a question. How to convert white pixels to png format?
 [This İmage](http://i.hizliresim.com/Q27N0k.png)